# What determines what can be pied-piped and what not in wh-movement?

Tags: grammar, questions, prepositional-phrases, pied-piping, wh-questions

- A wh-expression without wh-movement, where the wh-word is the object of the preposition “*about*”:

  > You are talking about **what**?
- A sentence that has undergone wh-movement:

  > **What** are you talking about?
- ⸺with a pied-piped “*about*”:

  > *About **what*** are you talking?
- The entire wh-clause has gotten pied-piped. Acceptable or not?

  > *Talking about **what*** are you?

---

#### Similarly <sub>(I find)</sub>,

[image: From Google search results]

- A wh-expression without wh-movement, where the wh-word is the object of the preposition “*of*”:

  > Chills and headache are symptoms of **what**?
- That above, with wh-movement applied:

  > **What** are chills and headache symptoms of?
- ⸺with a pied-piped “*of*”. Acceptable or not?

  > *Of **what*** are chills and headache symptoms?
- The entire wh-clause has gotten pied-piped. Acceptable or not?

  > *Symptoms of **what*** are chills and headache?

---

## Here’s the question⸻

**What exactly determines what can be pied-piped and what cannot in wh-movement?**

---

- <sub>By “pied-piping,” I mean [it in the linguistic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping). “A wh-word taking adjacent words together when moved.”</sub>
- <sub>I’ve come from [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/283099/38724) as my question was told to be esoteric for the website.</sub>

Comment: @Konstantin: Please don't cross-post. If the ELL community thinks your question should be asked here [or even on Linguistics] *instead,* then the question can be migrated from ELL to its new home. Delays in that process can be frustrating, but that's the system we have.

Comment: @PeterShor I wasn’t sure if it’s idiomatic or not as I’m not a native English speaker. I thought I heard the sentence structure somewhere, but now that you tell me it’s not idiomatic, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: These are interesting questions, but could you edit to ask just one question? And if you search for "pied piping barriers" I think you'll get the answer to several of your questions. Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement and look for "barriers." (The linguistic theory is that there are some phrasal *islands* that need to be moved together when they cross *barriers*. And some barriers are not allowed to be crossed, depending on the language.)